# Add fields to a Task without needing it in the Process?

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow, viewflow

I am currently using ViewFlow to model the process of creating websites in my company. My flow produces a website from an AWS instance to a E commerce site.

Each Task in my flow adds a little bit of information to my site. Examples: pick domain, configure SSL. Every time a task is completed I will ask my users for some information that will be saved to a website database row.

I am interested to know whether it is possible to add fields to a Task that doesn't require schema change in the my Process table. The reason I want this is because many of my tasks are asking my users for information that will be saved directly to our database. I do not need my process table to carry so much information that is only useful to one task.

Right now, if you have `fields=['field_not_in_schema', ...]` you will get an error `Unknown field(s) (field_not_in_schema) specified for MyProcess`.

I am using Viewflow's default frontend module. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [Flow.task_class](http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_flow.html#viewflow.base.Flow.task_class) in your flow to point to a custom task model, It's same as the `process_class` points to a custom process model.
ss
Of your tsk model are not inherited from the viewflow task model, you need to develop custom frontend.